# How to harness for loop with functionality of multiple buttons

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am stuck with code below. Either I cannot find simple answer to my problem due to not narrow enough search or I am just too blind to see. Anyway I am looking to put the "+" and "-" buttons to use. They suppose to literally do what their assigned symbols do.
With my level of python knowledge I can only achieve that by creating single function to each button which is a lot of code. I wonder if it is possible to create loop which could save tons of code and still be able to update label called "stock" in the same row as pressed button. At the moment I have assigned random numbers to that label, but in a bigger scope that label will be populated by integers taken from db.
I will be very grateful if anyone could point me into right direction.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Tk
import random

root = tk.Tk()

my_list=dict(AAA=["aa1", "aa2", "aa3"],
            BBB=["ab1", "ab2", "ab3", "ab4", "ab5"],
            CCC=["ac1", "ac2", "ac3", "ac4", "ac5", "ac6"],
            DDD=["ad1", "ad2", "ad3", "ad4", "ad5", "ad6"],
            EEE=["ae1", "ae2", "ae3", "ae4", "ae5", "ae6"],
            FFF=["af1", "af2", "af3", "af4", "af5", "af6"],
            GGG=["ag1", "ag2", "ag3", "ag4", "ag5", "ag6"],
            HHH=["ah1", "ah2", "ah3", "ah4", "ah5", "ah6"])

for x, y in enumerate(my_list):
   xyz=x*4
   tk.Label(root, text=y, width=25, bd=3, relief=tk.GROOVE).grid(row=0, column=xyz,columnspan=4,padx=(0,10))
   for xing, ying in enumerate(my_list[y]):
       tk.Label(root, text=ying, width=10,relief=tk.SUNKEN).grid(row=xing+1, column=xyz)
       stock=tk.Label(root,text=random.randint(0,9), width=5,relief=tk.SUNKEN)
       stock.grid(row=xing+1, column=xyz+1)
       tk.Button(root, text="+", width=3).grid(row=xing+1, column=xyz+2)
       tk.Button(root, text="-", width=3).grid(row=xing+1, column=xyz+3,padx=(0,10))

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your trying to add to strings? It would be alot better if you would actually give an example of what you want

Comment: By pressing "+" in certain row I want to add +1 (as integer) to already allocated integer in label called stock in the same row as pressed button "+", so given integer value 1 in row let say 3 will increase value to 2  by pressing "+" and to 0 by pressing "-".

Comment: Still its hard to figure out a way for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be solved by using *default value* of lambda argument as below:

```py
# function to adjust the value of "lbl" by "delta"
def adjust_value(lbl, delta):
    MIN, MAX = 0, 100   # set the range you want
    v = lbl['text'] + delta
    if MIN <= v <= MAX:
        lbl['text'] = v

for x, y in enumerate(my_list):
   xyz=x*4
   tk.Label(root, text=y, width=25, bd=3, relief=tk.GROOVE).grid(row=0, column=xyz,columnspan=4,padx=(0,10))
   for xing, ying in enumerate(my_list[y]):
       tk.Label(root, text=ying, width=10,relief=tk.SUNKEN).grid(row=xing+1, column=xyz)
       stock=tk.Label(root,text=random.randint(0,9), width=5,relief=tk.SUNKEN)
       stock.grid(row=xing+1, column=xyz+1)
       inc_btn = tk.Button(root, text="+", width=3)
       inc_btn.grid(row=xing+1, column=xyz+2)
       dec_btn = tk.Button(root, text="-", width=3)
       dec_btn.grid(row=xing+1, column=xyz+3,padx=(0,10))
       # using default value to argument of lambda
       inc_btn.config(command=lambda lbl=stock: adjust_value(lbl, +1))
       dec_btn.config(command=lambda lbl=stock: adjust_value(lbl, -1))
```

Note that if you want to access those "stock" values, you need to use a list or dict to store the "stock" labels.

Comment: Thank you so much, that solves the problem perfectly. You sir, are genius. I was cracking my head on this since more than a week and the answer is by the look of it pretty simple.  Thanks a bunch. Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are only using 2 buttons for this, I think having 2 functions won't be too bad. However, if you would have more than 2 buttons, I think a lambda function would be good. I'm not sure what your code is trying to accomplish here but my best guess is that you are trying to add and subtract numbers? I made a calculator gui a while back. For each button you would use a lambda function. I made a general function called expression(a) which would take a as a string and add it to the final output. Each button had the command of `command=lambda: expression(symbol)` so the + button would be `command=lambda: expression('+')` I think this will help you out.